# Apache FOP, scale image down to exact size in millimeters

Tags: java, image, apache-fop

I'm trying to scale an image down to exact specifications, `87mm x 10mm`, but I'm not getting it down to the right size.

I'm using Apache FOP 2.0, here's my fop.xconf:

```
<fop version="1.0">

<strict-configuration>true</strict-configuration>
<strict-validation>true</strict-validation>
<base>./</base>
<font-base>./</font-base>

<source-resolution>72</source-resolution>
<target-resolution>72</target-resolution>

<default-page-settings height="11in" width="8.26in"/>

</fop>
```

Here's the snippet that is supposed to display the image, it displays the image, but never getting down to the size I've specified.

```
 <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
    <fo:block font-size="3pt" text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
        <fo:external-graphic src="data:image/png;base64, {{barcodeimage}}" content-width="87mm" width="100%" content-height="10mm" scaling="non-uniform"/>
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
        {{barcodetext}}
    </fo:block>
</fo:flow>
```

Switching to height and width and the image doesn't resize at all:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="data:image/png;base64, {{barcodeimage}}" width="87mm" height="10mm" scaling="non-uniform"/>
```

I've tried playing around with `pt` instead of `mm` with no success, tried switching to `px` by using this formula `px = mm * dpi / 25.4` and still no luck.

Using `em` instead of `mm` and `content-width` instead of `width`, the image shrinks, but I have no idea, how to convert from `mm` to `em` units.

What I need is for a large image to be displayed scaled down to `87mm` width and `10mm` height, what is the correct way to do it?

**Update**: It seems the image displays correctly, the page size is incorrect, here's a screenshot taken in Okular PDF Viewer:

[image: screenshot]

And this is my full page XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin="1cm">
            <fo:region-body margin-top="18mm"/>
            <fo:region-before extent="0"/>
            <fo:region-after extent="0"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>

    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple">

        <!-- Page Header Goes Here -->
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
            <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="center" font-weight="normal">
                Test BarCode
            </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>

        <!-- Page Footer Goes Here -->
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
            <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="center">
                Page
                <fo:page-number/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>

        <!-- Page Body Goes Here -->
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

             <fo:block text-align="center">
                <fo:external-graphic src="data:image/png;base64, barcodeimage" content-width="87mm" content-height="10mm" scaling="non-uniform"/>
             </fo:block>
             <fo:block font-size="5pt" text-align="center" font-weight="normal">
                barcodetext
             </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>

    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you need using `content-width`, `content-height` and `scaling`:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="data:image/png;base64, {{barcodeimage}}" 
    content-width="87mm" content-height="10mm" 
    scaling="non-uniform"/>
```

To summarize the role of the different properties:

- `content-width` and `content-height` control the **image size**
- `scaling` controls the **image aspect ratio** (either preserved or modified to fit the desired image size)
- `width` and `height` control the **viewport size** through which the image is seen; it could be bigger than the image size, thus leaving some empty gap, or smaller than the image size
- `overflow` states what to do if the viewport size is smaller than the image size

*(disclosure: I'm a FOP developer, though not very active lately)*

Comment: So `mm` is supported, I was just using it incorrectly, thanks @Ifurini!

Comment: I've updated my question, it seems the page size is incorrect, any idea why my page size is so out of proportion?

Comment: @JanVladimirMostert that's really strange; using your FO file as input I get, as expected, a normal A4 page (both using your fop.xconf and with no configuration).

Comment: I've opened the PDF in a different viewer  and it looks right this time. Seems the issue was in Okular :-|